# Why was this edit suggestion rejected?

Tags: support, rejected-edits

Actually, I cannot understand why [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1662645) had been rejected.

Didn't the post have formatting problems? Or my edit was minor?

Comment: Yes the OP has issues, but so did the edit. That spacing was horrendous.

Comment: @Mike If you look at the markdown diffs, it looks like 888 just didn't notice the trailing spaces. And then Blumer, who edited, unchecked the "helpful" box because he needed to change too much still (but overlooked some himself).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reviewer Blumer decided to improve your suggested edit. Looking at the rendered output view, it seems your edit caused quite some trouble with the code block. It inserted a horrendous amount of spacing. Looking at the original source, this is actually not your doing. The spacing was already there, but not apparent until after your correction.

This user went in and corrected that and ultimately decided that your suggestion was not helpful. Most likely since it seemed you created a mess. This most likely caused the rejection.

Comment: Note that the reviewer might have thought that 888 added the whitespace, or simply rejected it because 888 failed to remove it given the obvious and significant problems it causes.  If it were me I know I'd reject it (while improving to correct the issue, as the reviewer did here), even though it's clear from the markdown that the OP is the one who added all the extra whitespace.

Comment: @Servy Your comment is way too slow for my ninja-editing skills.

Comment: No.  Your post makes it seem like Blumer didn't notice that 888 didn't cause the problem.  I'm saying maybe he did and maybe he didn't, but regardless, 888's edit should still have been rejected for failing to fix the problems left in there by the OP.

Comment: I didn't look at the rendered output view before. Now I understand, and I agree with the rejection. Thank you.

Comment: @Servy Meh, thinking with my review hat on, I see a perfectly fine (though unindented) code block on the left and an utter mess on the right. That would lead me to think "what on earth did the editor do". But you might be right. Anyway, improvement warranted, rejection up to the improver.

Comment: @888 It's not a problem.  As long as you don't make a habit of suggesting edits that are rejected there are no negative consequences, and this is certainly an understandable mistake to make.

Comment: @Bart Well, do you use markdown or rendered output view by default?  That affects the decision.  Also, whenever an edit doesn't make sense, my first instinct is to switch to the other view, as it's common for an edit to clearly indicate what's going on in one view but not the other.

Answer (score 2):

The hint is this line:

> Blumer reviewed this 9 mins ago: **Edit**

Someone edited your edit, so the original edit was "rejected". Never fear -- your changes were accepted, just not in their original form.

Comment: Improving a suggested edit only causes a rejection if the "helpful" box is unchecked.