# Why was this edit suggestion rejected by Community?

Tags: support, community-user, rejected-edits

Why was [this edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1888148) rejected by Community?

What is wrong? Is it minor?

From my [previous question about rejected edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170513/why-was-this-edit-suggestion-rejected) I learned that it could happen if a rewiewer find something wrong and update your edit, but I checked and nobody else edited the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910598/helpppp-android-google-map-v2) up to now.

Comment: @JoshCaswell The suggestion was rejected almost 7 minutes after the question was posted; why isn't the new revision in the history?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I can't understand: the question was rejected 21 minutes ago and in the question page there isn't any edit.

Comment: A telling question, @MichaelMrozek. I did my math wrong.

Comment: The edit was perfectly fine, I share your wonder here and will follow this post, hopefully dev will be able to shed some light over this.