# Edit suggestion rejected don't know why

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, badges, meta

First of all this is not a duplicate of [why was this edit suggestion rejected by community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175867/why-was-this-edit-suggestion-rejected-by-community).

Last day I was browsing questions on MSE and I found a mistake(or you call it the criteria of Explainer badge is wrongly written) on a question [New three-tiered badge idea: Explainer -> Refiner -> Illuminator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239898/new-three-tiered-badge-idea-explainer-refiner-illuminator).

In the question it is written as:

- **Explainer (Bronze):** Answered & edited 10 questions

I reviewed the criteria on [MSE Badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) and it is written clearly that:

- **Explainer (Bronze):** Edited and answered 1 question (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)

---

The criteria of awarding Explainer Badge is changed and the badge is currently awarded on Edited and answered 1 question (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0) on [MSE Badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges), [MSO Badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) and [SO Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges).

That's why I made an edit suggestion just because lot's of users visits this question everyday and they are misleading with this information. I made some improvement in the post by adding the criteria properly and initially my edit was approved by afterwards it was rejected by other users.

**I didn't do it for gaining reputation but the whole point of this question is wasted if the core criteria of awarding such badges is wrongly written.**

Could someone explains me that either my edit was wrong or my reputation is not enough for you guys to take [my edit suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/38217) seriously?

I am an active user on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3240038/joker) and continuously contributing in this community.

---

**EDIT:**

The comment that I left for edit suggestion reviewers:

It is not correct "Answered & edited 10 questions". Explainer is currently awarding on "Answered & edited 1 question" as it is written on badges page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your reputation. The edit, while well-intentioned, was unfortunately inappropriate. And here's why.

The users who rejected [your edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/38217) left the following reason:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

Take a closer look at that question. It's not an announcement of the new badges, it's a *proposal*.

What you're attempting to edit was the original *suggested* criteria for the badge, not necessarily the implementation we ended up with. Editing it would change the whole proposal and make the discussion in the answers and comments much harder to follow.

See also [Tim Post's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239898/new-three-tiered-badge-idea-explainer-refiner-illuminator?answertab=active#comment786062_239898) (emphasis mine):

> I want to thank everyone so far that has provided feedback, you folks are just amazing. **So far, I'm pretty convinced that we'd have to drop the bronze requirements down a bit, those need to be a bit easier to earn.** I need to think about concerns regarding folks gaming to get the badge (and the annoyance that can create), as well as the time window being a bit too narrow. Thank you, everyone for making this as productive as its been today - and please keep at it for any ideas or concerns that have not come up yet. I think most like the idea, I'm going to take another look at the mechanics.

That's exactly what happened. The requirements were reduced from 10 questions to 1. When it comes to feature requests (even ones that come from employees), you gotta expect changes between initial idea and implementation plus as the sites grow and we tweak things along the way.

Comment: Ok I read the @Tim Post's comment but its quite at the bottom so may be that's why I missed it.

Comment: @Joker Fair enough. But, right above the criteria, it says "Here's the proposed tiers for the badge". You have to read the whole post and interpret things in context. :)

Comment: @Joker Nah, no issue at all. You're in the right place to ask this sort of thing.

Comment: Well that's great. It means I should refrain from editing such discussion/proposal posts.

Comment: @Joker, no if there is spelling or similar, edit. If it needs it to clarify, do it. But make sure the edit is valid, and does mean what the author wanted.